# QtWebKit bridge: call JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyside, qwebkit

I am writing a hybrid application with HTML interface and Python code.
I can access Python functions via a shared object:

**pythonPart.py**:

```
class BO(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BO, self).__init__(parent)

    @Slot(str)
    def doStuff(self, txt):
        print(txt)

bridgeObj = BO()

# init stuff and frame...
frame.addToJavaScriptWindowObject( 'pyBridge', bridgeObj )
frame.evaluateJavaScript('alert("Alert from Python")')
frame.evaluateJavaScript('testMe()')
frame.evaluateJavaScript('alert("Starting test");testMe();alert("Test over")')
```

**jsPart.js**:

```
function testMe() { alert('js function testMe called'); }

pyBridge.doStuff("bla");
testMe();
```

Calling Python functions from JS works, as does calling `testMe` from JS. Calling "standard" JS functions like `alert` from Python works, too.

The last two Python lines won't:
`evaluateJavaScript("testMe()")` doesn't do anything at all.
The last line executes the first alert and won't continue after that.

**EDIT**: I already tried having some `time.sleep()` between loading and calling the `evaluateJavaScript` and I'm loading the webpage from the local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the JavaScript just isn't loaded yet. Adding `time.sleep()` calls doesn't help for that, those will also block the Qt event loop from continuing, not just your Python code.

Try waiting for the page to have fully loaded instead, for example (using [the loadFinished signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#loadFinished):

```
def onLoad():
    frame.evaluateJavaScript('testMe()')

frame.loadFinished.connect(onLoad)
```

Aditionally, for getting more debug information in situations like this, you might want to implement [QtWebKit.QWebPage.javaScriptConsoleMessage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage).

Comment: Thank you... you were right in all points. On afterthought it's kind of silly to expect continued loading in the background while time.sleep()ing.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two errors in the example code.

Firstly, when you add the object to the javascript window, you call it "pyBridge", but you then try to reference it in the javascript as "bridgeObj". Obviously, this will throw a `ReferenceError` which will prevent any further execution of the script.

Secondly, the `doStuff` method is missing a `self` argument, which will cause a `TypeError` to be raised by PySide.

Dealing with those two issues should be enough to fix your example code, so long as you make sure that the bridge object is added to the javacsript window *before* the html is loaded. This step is required if you want to reference the bridge object in top-level javascript code. However, if the bridge object is only ever referenced in function-level code, it can be safely added to the javascript window after the html has loaded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. This was due to hasty creation of a minimal example, and not a problem in the real application. However, calling the bridge object from JS is not the problem, the problem is calling user-created JS functions from Python via .evaluateJavaScript("...")